# Why does my program crash if I search for missing BST item?

Tags: python, search, binary-search-tree, nodes

I've constructed a BST too hold words and I'm trying to finish my search function, however for some reason if I search for an item that doesn't exist in the BST my program will crash, however as far as I can tell it shouldn't be doing that?

```
def bst_search(root, target):
if root.value == target or root is None:
    print("Yes")
    return root
elif target < root.value:
    return bst_search(root.left, target)
elif target > root.value:
    return bst_search(root.right, target)
else:
    print("No")
```

But when I run it looking for an item that isn't in the list i get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Shouldn't it just default too the else and automatically print "No"? Or is the program just handing itself nothing during a recursive call and freaking out?

Comment: flip to `if root is None or root.value == target:` ; evaluation is left-to-right

Comment: Ahh I see, makes sense perfectly now. Thanks so much for the help